# How to import/compile uefi module using micropython?

Tags: micropython, uefi

Following the instructions on [MicroPythonTestFramework/MicroPythonPkg](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2-staging/tree/MicroPythonTestFramework/MicroPythonPkg), I can successfully run micropython.efi (using VS2015x86 instead of VS2017).

However importing the uefi module as given in the example on the above link fails:

```
FS0:\EFI\Python\> micropython.efi
MicroPython v1.9.4 on 2018-07-30; uefi version
Use Ctrl-D to exit, Ctrl-E for paste mode
>>> import Lib.Uefi.uefi as uefi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: no module named 'Lib.Uefi'
```

`MicroPythonDxe.efi` is in the same folder as `micropython.efi`.

How do I do to compile the uefi module into `MicroPythonDxe.efi`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to successfully import the Python UEFI module, you must have the UEFI Python library on your device and accessible.

The modules you are looking for are located in `MicroPythonPkg/MicroPythonDxe/Lib/Uefi`.

The device file system will end up looking something like below

```
FS0:\EFI\Python\Lib\Uefi\uefi.py
                        \features.py
                        \msr.py
                        \protocols.py
                        \register.py.... etc
```

Comment: That works. I was thinking that the libs are compiled into the DXE file. But looks like they aren´t.